# Meta tag viewport does nothing

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to get my website to be displayed at full scale in any mobile device, like in this example:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/otYxl.jpg]

As of now, the website opens automatically zoomed-in, and my clients don't like that. I thought adding the line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

would solve this, but it does nothing. I've tried playing with the `initial-scale` value to see if it worked and it does nothing. I've set it to `initial-scale=0.5`, for example, and it didn't change the way the page displayed (to clarify, it doesn't work neither on desktop browser nor on mobile devices).

I've been working on this for days, any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: To clarify, this is a mockup of what I [get](http://imgur.com/Ct5IQAL,9pfgGTJ#0) vs. what I [need](http://imgur.com/Ct5IQAL,9pfgGTJ#1).

Comment: Is your opera set to desktop view?

Comment: I'm not specifically trying to make this work on opera. The thing is, when I change the scale it does nothing, not on the desktop browser, not on IE for Windows Phone, nor on Opera for Android. Changing from mobile view to desktop view does nothing either. It's as if the <meta name="viewport"... > tag isn't being read.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You need to show some HTML and CSS, tell how you expected the tag to affect the rendering, and describe the differences between expected and observed behavior.

Comment: In IE for windows phone its normal, take a look at this posts http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html and http://nostrongbeliefs.com/why-i-think-we-shouldnt-use-css-viewport-in-ie10-for-now/

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I did just that on my original post? Currently the webpage loads zoomed in to the top-left corner, I simply want it to load completely zoomed-out, displaying the whole page just like in the picture I provided, no matter the device used. If you need a specific part of the code I'll post it; or if you can give me any clue as to what should I look for I'll do it, but as it is, I don't know what more can I provide that would be helpful to you.

Comment: You need to provide your actual code, preferably a minimal demo, but at least *some* example. The `meta` tag simply prevents the default scaling, and you can test this by using it vs. not using it in a trivial page `<!doctype html><title> </title><h1>Hello</h1>` (the font size changes radically). So what does *your* page have, and how do you expect the tag to affect *it*?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela All right then, [this](http://entia.esy.es/En) is the page in question. As of now, when opening the page on a mobile device I'm getting [this](http://imgur.com/Ct5IQAL,9pfgGTJ#0), what I want is for it to load automatically like [this](http://imgur.com/Ct5IQAL,9pfgGTJ#1).

Comment: You should include relevant code, or at least links, to the question itself. And from the links, it seems that what you actually want is the opposite of what you are asking for: you would get what you now present as what you want by *omitting* the `meta` tag. The result will be practically unreadable on small screens, of course.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela yep, that was it. I removed this line and it's now working as intended. Of course it's less readable and probably worse looking but that's what the client asked for and that's what he'll get. Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the meta tags below:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

and see it your request will be resolved.

Comment: Check all meta tags included in your pages...because it works properly for me!